# What's wrong with my predicate function?

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming

I'm trying to use "*remove_if*" method by *std::list*. I wanna delete the "special" element. Here some code:

```
Class A {
public: 
void foo(size_t id) {
tasks.remove_if(&A::IsEqual(id)); //Here I have an error
}

private:
std::list<Task> tasks;
struct IsEqual {
    IsEqual(const Task& value) : _value(value) {}
    bool operator() (const size_t id) {
        return (_value._id == id);
    }
    Task _value;
    };
};
```

Could someone explain where the mistake is?

Comment: In addition to the answers already given, what's the & doing in front of `A::IsEqual` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `operator()` should take a `Task` argument, since this is the type of the elements in `tasks`.

Another way to write it:

```
tasks.remove_if([id](const Task& t) { return t._id == id });
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a wrong functor. The constructor should take value to compare and the () operator should take Task:

```
struct IsEqual {

   IsEqual(const size_t id) : id(id) {}

   bool operator() (const Task& value) {
       return (value._id == id);
   }

   size_t id;
};
```

Comment: Oh, yes. I've swapped these parameters :(